# tomcat 7 @WebServlet

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am using Eclipse and Tomcat 7, on servlet I just add @WebServlet("className") so that I do not have to use or to put web.xml but when I try to start server (or tomcat) on console window and error occured saying

```
Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> FirstHello in servlet mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3108)
...
```

At first I did not put web.xml on project, then when the error shows I try to put web.xml but does not have servlet mapping

```
<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"> 
</web-app>
```

but still same error messge show on Console window of eclipse.

Anyone who could help me to see any error(s) that I am doing?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an illegal URL mapping pattern. Change `FirstHello` to `/FirstHello`

Comment: I missed that part. Thank you sir.